# Raspberry Pi 3 B+ Ubuntu mate Install

Tags: raspberry-pi

I bought raspberry pi 3 b+ Model. But I have a question about it.
In the main raspberry pi homepage. Ubuntu Mate can install raspberry pi 2,3.
So I want to know that Is is possible to install Ubuntu Mate on raspberry pi 3 b+ model. 
I'm confused about it because they only announced 2,3 model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

excuse me,

in my experience, it's impossible.

with image of https://ubuntu-mate.org/raspberry-pi/ and raspberry pi 3b+

what i got is only rainbow screen.

it seems that raspbian is easy answer.

Comment: Can you fill in a few blanks? Where did you put the image? Did you have to have a certain name for your flash drive? Did you have to do any additional setup?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible, I installed Ubuntu Mate about 3 weeks ago onto a Raspberry Pi 3B+. It's as simple as downloading Ubuntu Mate's Raspberry Pi image from their [download page](https://ubuntu-mate.org/raspberry-pi/) and flashing it onto an SD card.

For context I needed Ubuntu Mate because I wanted to use an Intel RealSense camera with the Pi, and was able to get the camera up and running without too much trouble by following their [installation guide](https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense/blob/master/doc/RaspberryPi3.md).

Comment: Thanks for the help. It helps me a lot

Comment: This for sure was NOT a 3B+ because the Ubutnu Mate download from your link does not yet support it.

Comment: @Elmi It absolutely **_was_** a 3B+, in fact I still have the SD card and just verified that it boots normally on my Pi 3B+. Not sure if something has changed since I wrote that answer, but it did indeed work at the time of writing.